# Play video on browser iphone and ipad

Tags: android, html, ios, video

I am trying to play video on browser using video tag in openwrt router, everything is working perfect in android devices, but in iOS its only showing play button. Nothing processed when clicked on play button.

```
<video loop autoplay controls="true" width='50%' height='50%' src="xyz.mp4" type='video/mp4'></video>
```

Please help me in this it will be great appreciation.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by installing nginx server, apple phones use byte code method to load videos and I was using uhttpd in my openwrt, and it does not support byte code method. So, I installed nginx server in it and now its working like a charm.